# How to properly float two elements side by side without breaking if window is resized

Tags: css

So I have two elements floated next to each other and one has a set width and the other needs to be a percentage so that when the window/browser is resized the content will flow with it.  However I am having trouble keeping the content floated next to each other when the window size is smaller than certain ratio.

Here is my css code:

```
.box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}

p {
    width: 95%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Is there a way around this?  Here is my fiddle so you can see what is going on. 
[My example](http://jsfiddle.net/3QhzS/)

If you make the size smaller you will see the P tag drops down below the box.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/3QhzS/1/

Comment: @Pete 's solution is a good one. Although I don't understand exactly what would you expect to happen.

Comment: adding `position:absolute;left:60px;` to `p` also works. http://jsfiddle.net/3QhzS/5/. not good as @Pete's.

Comment: Hi Pete, thanks for that and it works perfectly but this way means you need to know the size of the box...I understand my example shows a set width for the box but "what if" we don't know that before hand?  Is there a way to remedy that?  Just trying to learn other ways.  Thanks!

Comment: not really, the only way would be to use javascript to calculate the sizes and change the styles accordingly. unless you went the percentage route and gave your image a % width too

Comment: No worries..thanks again, please create an answer so I can accept it..

Comment: jquery version: http://jsfiddle.net/3QhzS/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the box is a fixed width you can use the following styles:

```
.item {
    padding-left: 60px;
}

.box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -60px;
    background-color: blue;
}

p {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3QhzS/1/

otherwise you will need to add a little bit of jquery to it to add styles on the fly:

http://jsfiddle.net/3QhzS/6/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the width of the `div.box` (as you stated in comments) then you can use `position:relative` to the `p` tag which will do the trick.

```
p{ 
  position:relative;
  /* anchoring top, left and right sides */
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  left:0px; 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3QhzS/9/)

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3QhzS/10/)(with two div's)